# Why does this JS loop re-write of the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have this web page that has a loop to write out a bunch of list elements.
On loading, the `for` loops runs 56 times, and uses the CSS styles and all.

But, I have the input button that runs the `loops()` functions running the `do` code block, and this basically reloads the page with the new list, and none of my other html appears.

How can I make a `loops()` that will add my list elements and grow the list rather than re-load the whole doc?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jscss.css">
 <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  function loops(){
    var i= 0;
 do{
   document.write("<li id='list'>"+i+"</li>");
    i++;
  }while(i < 100);
  }
  document.write("Hello World");
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("<input id='string' type='text'>");
  document.write("<input onClick='loops()' type='button'  value='Submit'>");
 document.write("<ul id='list'>");
 for (i = 0; i <= 56; i++) {
    document.write("<li>"+i+"</li>");
};
document.write("</ul>");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calling [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) after the document is loaded will clear the document.

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling
>   document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls
>   document.open which will clear the document.

So by the time you click the button, the document would have already loaded, so it is getting cleared.

You can use appendChild() or add the new content to the innerHTML of the parent element

```js
function loops() {
  var i = 0,
    lst = document.getElementById('list'),
    html = '';
  do {
    html += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
  } while (++i < 100);
  lst.innerHTML += html;
}
document.write("Hello World");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<input id='string' type='text'>");
document.write("<input onClick='loops()' type='button'  value='Submit'>");
document.write("<ul id='list'>");
for (i = 0; i <= 56; i++) {
  document.write("<li>" + i + "</li>");
};
document.write("</ul>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `document.write()` don't use `document.write()`. Google `innerHTML`.